# How to pass javascript processed data over to PHPmailer? Do I need to run a mail server on my comptuer (win 7)?

Tags: javascript, php, phpmailer

So essentially I get a string out of javascript of the warmest cities in the world right now by making use of the weather API. but then I want to take that STRING and pass it through to mail.php to be mailed to myself.

```
        httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

        httpRequest.open("GET", api, false);

        httpRequest.send();

        var returned = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);

        var string = "";

        for(var i = 0; i < returned.items.length; i++){
            console.log(returned.items[i].link);

            string += returned.items[i].link + ", " +  "\n";


        }
        console.log("HellO");
        console.log(string)


function post(path, params, method) {
method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

// The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
// It can be made less wordy if you use one.
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", method);
form.setAttribute("action", path);

for(var key in params) {
    if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    }
}

document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();

post(mail.php, string, POST)
```

and then on my mail.php I Have

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require './PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require './PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require './PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use     
SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                       // Specify main and 
backup server
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP 
authentication
$mail->Username = 'email@email.com';                   // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'password';               // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 
'ssl' also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    //Set the SMTP port 
number - 587 for authenticated TLS
$mail->setFrom('email@email.com', 'Amit Agarwal');     //Set who the message 
 is to be sent from
$mail->addReplyTo('labnol@gmail.com', 'First Last');  //Set an alternative 
reply-to address
$mail->addAddress('josh@example.net', 'Josh Adams');  // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 
characters
// $mail->addAttachment('/usr/labnol/file.doc');         // Add attachments
// $mail->addAttachment('/images/image.jpg', 'new.jpg'); // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to 
HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = POST['string'];
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images 
to embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));

if(!$mail->send()) {
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}

echo 'Message has been sent';
```

but yet no matter what happens that email doesn't send. In order to send a php email do I need a mail server open on my windows 7 box, do i need a php.ini file (if so what for), and am I sending the mail out wrong.

Im going javscript > Weather API > JAVASCRIPT > STRING > EMAIL

yet its not sending.

I've been trying for a while now and I just can't figure out what exactly Im missing.

Comment: _"do I need a web server"_ - Yes. You could probably manage with PHP's built in server. _"do i need a php.ini file (if so what for)"_ - I would recommend that you do some research... Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)